# Specify proper line in listBox using C# Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, button, listbox

I'm using C# Windows Forms Application to create a simple application. I've used a listBox to read and display a text file (10 lines). How to specify the First, Last, Previous and Next line in the listBox by pressing a proper button? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.
[enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to specify the First, Last, Previous and Next line in the listBox by pressing a proper button?

**Note**: *This answer assumes you want only show one line at a time, either it be the first line, next, previous and or last line in the text file.*

***Let's first go over*** your current approach. The routine `button6_Click` is only trying to load a file, read the line and if the line/string is not `null` then add this string to `listBox1`; this is doing this for every string in that file. The usage of `OpenFileDialog` and `StreamReader` implement `IDisposable`, you should wrap these in a `using` block to ensure objects are properly disposed of as well.

***Your current approach*** is more than likely not what you need as you don't want to load everything up at once, only when needed. With this in mind, you would need to keep some sort of `collection` of these lines from the file; there's more than a few ways, but I will focus on just one way.

First, create a new class as per below:

```
public class NavigateFile
{
    // Stores the file lines collection
    public IEnumerable<string> CurrentFileLines { get; private set; }

    // Tracks the current line index
    public int CurrentFileLineIndex { get; private set; } = 0;

    // Tracks the next line index
    public int NextFileLineIndex { get; private set; } = 1;

    // Tracks the previous line index
    public int PreviousFileLineIndex { get; private set; } = -1;

    // Tracks the last line index
    public int LastFileLineIndex { get; private set; } = 0;

    // Routine to load the file
    public void LoadFile()
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                CurrentFileLines = File.ReadLines(ofd.FileName).Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line));

        CurrentFileLineIndex = 0;
        NextFileLineIndex = 1;
        PreviousFileLineIndex = -1;
        LastFileLineIndex = CurrentFileLines.Count();
    }

    // Routine return the first line in the file
    public string GoToFirstLine()
    {
        CurrentFileLineIndex = 0;
        return CurrentFileLines.ToList()[CurrentFileLineIndex];
    }

    // Routine return the next line in the file if we can
    public string GoToNextLine()
    {
        if((CurrentFileLineIndex + 1) <= CurrentFileLines.Count() - 1)
        {
            CurrentFileLineIndex++;
            return CurrentFileLines.ToList()[CurrentFileLineIndex];
        }   

        return CurrentFileLines.ToList()[CurrentFileLineIndex];
    }

    // Routine return the previous line in the file if we can
    public string GoToPreviousLine()
    {
        if ((CurrentFileLineIndex - 1) >= 0 && (CurrentFileLineIndex - 1) <= CurrentFileLines.Count())
        {
            CurrentFileLineIndex--;
            return CurrentFileLines.ToList()[CurrentFileLineIndex];
        }

        return CurrentFileLines.ToList()[CurrentFileLineIndex];
    }

    // Routine return the last line in the file
    public string GoToLastLine()
    {
        CurrentFileLineIndex = CurrentFileLines.Count() - 1;
        return CurrentFileLines.Last();
    }

}
```

Next you could use this simply by calling a few functions to return what you would need. Put below logic in your specific buttons to handle what you would need to.

```
 // put this in your class where you will be using the new class
 private NavigateFile NavigateFile { get; set; } = new NavigateFile();

 // Load a file
 listBox1.Items.Clear();
 NavigateFile.LoadFile();
 listBox1.Items.Add(NavigateFile.GoToFirstLine());

 // Go to first line
 listBox1.Items.Clear();
 listBox1.Items.Add(NavigateFile.GoToFirstLine());

 // Go to next line
 listBox1.Items.Clear();
 listBox1.Items.Add(NavigateFile.GoToNextLine());

 // Go to previous line
 listBox1.Items.Clear();
 listBox1.Items.Add(NavigateFile.GoToPreviousLine());

 // Go to last line in the file
 listBox1.Items.Clear();
 listBox1.Items.Add(NavigateFile.GoToLastLine());
```

If you should need to lookup an item, you can build a `Linq` query against `CurrentFileLines` in the `NavigateFile` class and pull what you would need, it may be helpful if needed somewhere.

**Note:**

I was clearing out the `listBox1.Items` every time I did something, you don't have to, but I did. Also keep in mind, make sure you have a file loaded before calling any of these functions and or edit them to make sure you have data. If there is something you don't understand, please let me know and I can help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your answer is work and helps a lot!

Comment: @user12447693 you are welcome, glad to be of help, also good question by the way!

Answer (score 0):

I ~think~ you're asking how to change the **selected** item in the listbox by pressing the buttons?

If so, something like:

```
OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();

private void btnLoadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
    {
        try
        {
            List<String> lines = new List<String>(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(openFile.FileName));
            lines.RemoveAll(l => l.Trim().Length == 0);
            if (lines.Count > 0)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                listBox1.Items.AddRange(lines.ToArray());
            }                    
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error Loading File");
        }                
    }
}

private void btnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}

private void btnLast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = (listBox1.Items.Count - 1);
    }
}

private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = (listBox1.SelectedIndex > 0) ? (listBox1.SelectedIndex - 1) : 0;
    }
}

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = (listBox1.SelectedIndex < (listBox1.Items.Count - 1)) ? (listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1) : (listBox1.Items.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

Note that if no item is currently selected, then pressing previous or next will select the first item in the listbox.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your answer helps a lot!